# Python/Pycharm on a nas server

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, plotly-dash, nas

I recently upgraded my mac-mini with external hard drives to a proper NAS server (DS920+).
With the mac-mini I installed Pycharm and was able to code/develop a few projects on it. Now with the NAS server, I can't find a tutorial on how to install pycharm. It seems that everything has to be done in command-line. Isn't there a way to have a proper IDE? or do I need to create a virtual machine with windows for instance and there I would install pycharm (?) My goal is not to develop code on the nas but rather on my local PC (mostly scripts for data fetching/automation) and have a nice user interface on the nas (and not the command line window)

Furthermore I have developped a web server based on dash/plotly. Ideally I would like to have the webserver deployed on the nas. So I have a collection of .py files and a main.py which lauches the web server. I would need to use "docker" in order to deploy my code onto the nas right?

Comment: If your NAS is attached to your Mac-mini, then doesn't the Mac already give you an environment other than command line?

Comment: Yes that's what I was doing up until getting my NAS. My goal is to remove the mac-mini eventually.

Comment: I see. What will handle the compute aspect, though? The hard drives need to be connected will something on your network.

Comment: It will be the server itself ie the NAS from synology. One solution could be to use Docker and make an image of pycharm (it is just a guess, so this could be very dumb); in the meantime I will ssh into the server to install packages and will run my python scripts via the task manager :(